# Why does =~ operator give a syntax error on Solaris while comparing with a regular expression

Tags: linux, shell-script, regular-expression, solaris, ksh

I used this following piece of code

```
appcount_range="^[1-$APP_COUNT]$"
    until [[ $APP_OPTION =~ $appcount_range ]]
    do
            echo "INVALID CHOICE! Please enter a valid option:"
            read APP_OPTION
    done
```

It checks if the menu option is entered correctly. And since the APP_COUNT is dynamically decided I cannot hardcode the valid options. This piece of code runs perfectly on a Linux based server with ksh93 but the same code gives a syntax error on a Solaris server with ksh88 saying:

`syntax error at line ## : '=~' unexpected`

Why isn't `=~` a recognized opeartor in ksh88 and what should I use as an alternative to compare a regex?

Comment: This does not depend on the operating system but on the shell. What shell are you using on Solaris (and what version of the shell)? I'm assuming you are using a recent version of `bash` on the Linux system?

Comment: I was using ksh shell on both solaris and linux system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an error that ksh88 (the `/bin/ksh` of Solaris 10 and older, and `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`) would output.

While the `[[ ... ]]` syntax does come from ksh, `=~` inside is one of the very few actual bashisms. `bash` actually was the shell that introduced it (in version 3.0).

It's been added later to `ksh93` (so would work with the `/bin/sh` and `/bin/ksh` of Solaris 11 and newer) and `zsh`, with variations (a `=~` operator is also available in the `test`/`[` builin of `zsh` and `yash`). ksh88 has not been updated since the 90s (other than for bug fixes, or POSIX conformance fixes on some systems).

Here, you don't need  a regexp though, a wildcard pattern will work as  well:

```
[[ $APP_OPTION = [1-$APP_COUNT] ]]
```

With the `=` operator (from ksh), the right hand operand is a wildcard pattern. Or you could use the standard way to do pattern matching:

```
case $APP_OPTION in
  [1-$APP_COUNT]) ...
esac
```

Note that it wouldn't work for any value greater than 9. `[1-12]`, same as `[21-1]` matches on 2 and 1 only (and possibly other characters that collate the same as `1` in some locales)).

ksh wildcard patterns are functionally equivalent to extended regular expressions (except for the `{x,y}` interval operators in modern variants of EREs) though with a different syntax:

- `.` -> `?`
- `.*` -> `*`
- `x*` -> `*(x)`
- `x|y` -> `@(x|y)`
- `x?` -> `?(x)`
- `x+` -> `+(x)`
- `[^x]` -> `[!x]`
- `x{3,5}` -> `xxx?(x)?(x)` (ksh93 has `{3,5}(x)`, not in ksh88).

If you still needed to use regular expressions, you'd need to use a separate utility:

```
expr "x$string" : "x$regexp" # BRE, anchored at the start

STRING=$string RE=$regexp command -p awk '
  BEGIN{exit(!(ENVIRON["STRING"] ~ ENVIRON["RE"]))}'
```

Comment: This wildcard pattern matching will work for this particular problem. But what if I need to use a regular expression in ksh88?

Comment: bash-3.1 is from 2008, but ksh93 introduced this feature in 2006 already.

Comment: @schily, bash-3.1 is from 2005 (bash had code for =~ in earlier versions IIRC but it was commented out or under #ifdefs)

Comment: OK, the tar file is from 2008 but `star -tv -newest-file` says Dec 7 2005. Then this seems to be one of the rare innovations in bash that is not from ksh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas how to compare a variable with a regular expression in ksh version 88?

Comment: @PratikMayekar, see edit.

Comment: @schily, I did not remember correctly actually. That `=~` was added in 3.0. And the ifdefed-out `=~` in earlier  versions was also for wildcard patterns, not RE.